# split string with character

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, split, character

using SQL 2008; I have the following string:

```
EMCo: 1 WorkOrder: 12770      WOItem: 10
```

I am trying to get the WorkOrder #.

When the string did not have the WOItem on end of it, I was able to use the following statement to get WorkOrder #.

```
[WorkOrder] = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(HQMA.KeyString,CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(HQMA.KeyString))-1)))
```

This statement moves and may have double digits for the Co#, and it does not always have WOItem #.  Was hoping to find something that would split after the ":" and just take 2nd group.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patindex suggestion above will work beautifully, now if you still want to use your current statement, substring will pull the same values, and replace will take out WOItem. Not very elegant, it works whether you have WOItem or not:

```
select substring(LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(REPLACE(HQMA.KeyString,'WOItem:',''),
CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(REPLACE(HQMA.KeyString,'WOItem:','')))-1))),0,7)


select substring(LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(REPLACE(HQMA.KeyString,'WOItem:',''),
CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(REPLACE(HQMA.KeyString,'WOItem:','')))-1))),0,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `patindex()`?  Assuming the work order always has five characters:

```
select substring(HQMA.KeyString,
                 patindex('%WorkOrder: %', HQMA.KeyString) + 11,
                 5) as WorkOrder
```

Comment: I do have some Work Orders that are 4 characters

Comment: @Kerry . . . This should work for those as well, if you trim the spaces from the results.